# share content on whatsapp iphone app xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, webview, uiwebview

looking for answer over a 2 months now..please help

i am using webview to create my ios app and in my mobile website there is whatsapp share button which shares content to whatsapp and it works fine on any browser, for android app i have implement code to make it work..

this is my whatsapp code in my website:

> href="whatsapp://send" data-text="content goes here" data-href=""
>   class="wa_btn wa_btn_s" style="display:none">Share

and this is what i am using in my xcode

```
func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool { if (request.url!.scheme == "whatsapp") { let wurl = URL(string: "whatsapp://")!

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(wurl, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    } else { UIApplication.shared.openURL(wurl) 
    } 
    return false
}
return true
}
```

it opens whatsapp but there is no content if i use it like this:

> string: "whatsapp://sendtext="hello world"

it shares hello world, but i want to share the content from site.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Please fix your question, it should be: whatsapp://send?text=hello%20world

Answer (score 1):

You should use the following string, if you want to share a website page via Whatsapp through **Mobile-Web**:

```
whatsapp://send?text=http://www.yourwebsite.com
```

Using the webpage link in the text will allow Whatsapp to take the metadata from the website (icon/description..etc) and use it in the message.

Comment: this will share my page http://www.yourwebsite.com.. but i want to share current page..

Comment: you can set any page that you want in the "text" field. you should know the context and share the current page.

Comment: thanks for reply,,

this is in my wordpress site for sharing on whatsapp

href="whatsapp://send" data-text="content goes here" data-href="" class="wa_btn wa_btn_s" style="display:none">Share

i want to share the same on iphone app.. can u tell me what should i write in app ?

Comment: Try this: <a href="whatsapp://send?text=http://www.yourwebpage.com/test/test.html" data-action="share/whatsapp/share">

Comment: yes, i have done this in my html page, now how to implement in xocde ?